# how to avoid 301 errors when serving static content using iis url rewrite

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I am trying my website to get images(static contents) from other server (or site) using IIS url rewrites. Below is the sameple rule written where it checks for any image request and serves it from another website on same server

```
 <rule name="image" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^Images/(.+)$" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost/PGFeedReadAPI/Images/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
 </rule>
```

This works fine and I am getting results however with 301 error i.e. request goes to server it response with 301 (moved permanently) to browser and then browser makes fresh request to new url. Can we avoid this round tripping? I would prefer to achieve this without any code changes (i.e. with only configuration changes). Please pardon if I am missing some basic concepts.

Comment: The way you try to do it, with a simple rewrite, is not going to work. The concept of rewrite is to translate the visible url, to an inside url, and IIS can read and serve this inside url. Using external server this can not be possible work the way you believe, and thats why you see the redirect... the redirect is try to fix the wrong concept.

Comment: Can you suggest a better approach? I checked with other team in our organization who works on java based sites and they are able to rewrite rules in apache server which is not giving any 301 errors but serving content.

Comment: You need to make an ashx handler, and that handler read and serve the outside server files.

Comment: it seems my approach for using url rewrite in this case is not right as they are based on 301 permanent redirects only. Any suggestions how to achieve this with some configurations? @Aristos, can you provide some pointers for ashx handlers?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer from this post:
[Put images on CDN, using MVC3 on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892646/put-images-on-cdn-using-mvc3-on-iis7)

Use a response filter to change the urls **before** they make it to the client. This will avoid 301s.

I took this a step further and added caching so that I query the CDN on app start, hold a dictionary of the static file names to CDN urls and quickly swap in. It also auto-uploads missing files from local to CDN and adds them to the dictionary for future reference (asynchronously).

Comment: This sounds good but there is 1 isssue that I am trying to achieve this without any code changes in main project, but if required we are ok to write code outside of project (like http handlers and add them in iis). To give you more background, we have Single page website using backbone and require. So what it means is there is actually no .NET or MVC code. We are trying to use IIS as a pure web server. Let me know if this make sense. We are able to achieve it with combination tomcat and apache. Looking to do same with IIS.